# RewriteRule filename to minify valid url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, filenames, minify

I am trying to write a rewriterule that converts a filename to a minify valid url

This url

> example.com/min/cssall1.css

Should become

> example.com/min/?g=cssall

The code i already have is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^min/([a-zA-z]+)([0-9]+)\.(js|css)$ min/?g=$1 [L]
```

When i remove the ? at min/?g=$1 i get the following

> example.com/min/g=cssall

Which obviously is incorrect.
I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance

Danny

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rule with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^min/([^.]+)\.(js|css)$ /min/?g=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```